# Oracle group by row value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table of the following format:

```
Message ID Message
 1          User 1
 2          A1 4
 3          A2 6
 4          A3 5
 5          A4 7
 1          User 2
 2          A1 3
 3          A2 2
 4          A3 6
 5          A4 2
 1          User 1
 2          A1 4
 3          A2 6
 4          A3 5
 5          A4 7
 1          User 2
 2          A1 3
 3          A2 2
 4          A3 6
 5          A4 2
```

EDIT: There is also aditional timestamp column.

I would like to get the following output. In other words I want to get the sum grouped by users and actions

```
 User   Action Action sum
 User 1 A1       8
 User 1 A2      12
 User 1 A3      10
 User 1 A4      14
 User 2 A1       6
 User 2 A2       4
 User 2 A3      12
 User 2 A4       4
```

What is te best way to acomplish this ?

Comment: Is there any way to identify the user for an action? Are there any other columns that you haven't mentioned? As presented, there's no way to do this in a straight SQL query. PL/SQL might be an option if rows can be retrieved in a guaranteed order.

Comment: From what I can understand, the table is kind of partitioned by "User n" messages, and the "An" messages then relate to the previous "User n" found. But how is the order given ? Isn't there any other column showing that ? If not, then how can you guarantee this order ??

Comment: Sorry of forgot to include timestamp column which gives the order

Comment: @etna . . . Your data is hard to read.  Can you be explicit about what the columns are and what the values are in those columns?  For instance, is "A1 3" in one column or two?

Answer (score 1):

With the timestamp information, you can do:

```
with w as
(
  select t.*,
         regexp_substr(t.message, 'A\d+') action, -- Get action "An", where n is a number
         regexp_substr(t.message, ' (\d+)') quantity, -- Get quantity after blank
         (select max(t2.message) keep (dense_rank last order by t2.timestamp) u
          from your_table t2
          where t2.message like 'User %'
            and t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp) person
  from your_table t1
  order by t1.timestamp
)
select w.person, w.action, sum(to_number(w.quantity)) sum_quantity
from w
where w.action is not null
group by w.person, w.action
order by w.person, w.action
;
```

This gives:

```
PERSON  ACTION  SUM_QUANTITY
User 1  A1  8
User 1  A2  12
User 1  A3  10
User 1  A4  14
User 2  A1  6
User 2  A2  4
User 2  A3  12
User 2  A4  4
```

**Explanations :**

- `PERSON` is used instead of `USER` which is a reserved word in Oracle SQL (idem for `SUM`)
- I used regular expressions to get the action and quantity
- the hardest part is to associate the user to the lines that don't have any (with message like  `A1 4`). This is why I use a `dense_rank`: to make it quick, this means "give me for the current line the latest `message` like `User %` with a timestamp before the one of the current line"